# Blender is entirely messed up

Tags: 3d-view

This problem has been happening for a while. Just normally creating a new Blender file, and this is what I see first:

[image: blender general startup file]

And no, I'm not on Wireframe or anything. Just the basic startup scene.

Meshes (like sphere), looked entirely messed up...

[image: shpere mesh]

All other meshes are messed up and not visible. I've searched a lot for the problem, but none had the same problem as mine.

I tried reinstalling Blender, resetting default settings & even installing older version, i also reinstalled my Windows.

Maybe it's with my PC? Although it used to work pretty fine.

specs: **AMD A8-5500B APU with AMD Radeon HD 7560D**

Loading my other Blender files, makes it even worse! Nothing you see makes sense, just vertices all around the scene.

Comment: This looks like a GPU/drawing issue. Check to make sure your GPU is  on the list of supported cards - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/. Also, try updating your graphics drivers.

Comment: Some one else asked a very similar question yesterday (for some value of yesterday, anyway).

Comment: If blender was working fine earlier that means that something in the configuration changed. Did you update the OS? (or did it automatically update?) Reinstalling blender is hardly the solution. Updating or downgrading the drivers for the GPU might work. It would help if you edit your question and at least add information on what kind of system you are using, OS and GPU (and there is no need to use fowl language).

Comment: If latest drivers installed, I'd suggest file a bug report. Help > Report as Bug.